# MongoDb Indexes - Equal vs In filter and index usage

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework, compound-index

I've the follolowing model of a user

```
{
  "TenantId":"abc",
  "ContainerId": "xyz",
  "Name": "yyy",
  "Tags": [
      {
            "Key":"key1",
            "Value":"val1".  
      }
      .....
  ]
}
```

TenantId and containerId are in relation 1:n, so for one Tenant there may be multiple ContainerId items.

I've read that in order to get maximum index usage, the first field in index should be most selective, to minimise documents MongoDb needs to scan. What's more, some suggest that it's better to have "equality" filter on that field, instead of a range filter.
Now, I've added 2 indexes:

```
{
   "ContanerId":1,
   "Tags.Key": 1
}
{
   "TenantId":1,
   "Tags.Key": 1
}
```

Now executing 2 queries which are equal in the results they return:

```
find({"TenantId":"abc", "Tags.Key": {$in : ["1","2"]}})
find({"ContainerId":{$in:["abc","xyz",.....]}, "Tags.Key": {$in : ["1","2"]}})
```

I'd assume, that the first would run much faster, as it needs to examine less elements while scanning the index. However, it seems that results are almost identical.
Can someone help me and explain why the performance of both queries is similar ?

First query stats:

```
{
   "executionSuccess":true,
   "nReturned":171240,
   "executionTimeMillis":602,
   "totalKeysExamined":171240,
   "totalDocsExamined":171240,
   "executionStages":{
      "stage":"FETCH",
      "nReturned":171240,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate":579,
      "works":171241,
      "advanced":171240,
      "needTime":0,
      "needYield":0,
      "saveState":1338,
      "restoreState":1338,
      "isEOF":1,
      "invalidates":0,
      "docsExamined":171240,
      "alreadyHasObj":0,
      "inputStage":{
         "stage":"IXSCAN",
         "nReturned":171240,
         "executionTimeMillisEstimate":200,
         "works":171241,
         "advanced":171240,
         "needTime":0,
         "needYield":0,
         "saveState":1338,
         "restoreState":1338,
         "isEOF":1,
         "invalidates":0,
         "keyPattern":{
            "PyraTenantId":1,
            "IsEmpty":1,
            "Tags.KeyValue":1
         },
         "indexName":"PyraTenantIsEmptyTagsKeyValue",
         "isMultiKey":true,
         "multiKeyPaths":{
            "PyraTenantId":[

            ],
            "IsEmpty":[

            ],
            "Tags.KeyValue":[
               "Tags"
            ]
         },
         "isUnique":false,
         "isSparse":false,
         "isPartial":false,
         "indexVersion":2,
         "direction":"forward",
         "indexBounds":{
            "PyraTenantId":[
               "[\"01fbe4f9-77a5-48a2-8a3d-6b105808f6ac\", \"01fbe4f9-77a5-48a2-8a3d-6b105808f6ac\"]"
            ],
            "IsEmpty":[
               "[false, false]"
            ],
            "Tags.KeyValue":[
               "[\"01fbe4f9-77a5-48a2-8a3d-6b105808f6ackey6_ddd_01fbe4f9-77a5-48a2-8a3d-6b105808f6acvalue6\", \"01fbe4f9-77a5-48a2-8a3d-6b105808f6ackey6_ddd_01fbe4f9-77a5-48a2-8a3d-6b105808f6acvalue6\"]"
            ]
         },
         "keysExamined":171240,
         "seeks":1,
         "dupsTested":171240,
         "dupsDropped":0,
         "seenInvalidated":0
      }
   }
}
```

Second query stats:

```
 {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 171240,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 456,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 171412,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 171240,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "nReturned" : 171240,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 410,
            "works" : 171412,
            "advanced" : 171240,
            "needTime" : 171,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 1339,
            "restoreState" : 1339,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 171240,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 171240,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 290,
                "works" : 171412,
                "advanced" : 171240,
                "needTime" : 171,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 1339,
                "restoreState" : 1339,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "ContainerId" : 1,
                    "IsEmpty" : 1,
                    "Tags.KeyValue" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "ContainerIdIsEmptyTagsKeyValue",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "ContainerId" : [],
                    "IsEmpty" : [],
                    "Tags.KeyValue" : [ 
                        "Tags"
                    ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "ContainerId" : [ 
                        "[\"01ba96f4-2b21-4c66-ba8d-84fab56ab398\", \"01ba96f4-2b21-4c66-ba8d-84fab56ab398\"]", 
                        "[\"0295187c-5cbe-490d-ad04-83f51f890aec\", \"0295187c-5cbe-490d-ad04-83f51f890aec\"]", 
                        "[\"059ccb9c-0f50-45d7-a126-ad440e3488a2\", \"059ccb9c-0f50-45d7-a126-ad440e3488a2\"]", 
                        "[\"05a887dc-7b2f-4fa5-9256-2220d1d8158f\", \"05a887dc-7b2f-4fa5-9256-2220d1d8158f\"]", 
                        "[\"0d080dce-5d88-4a9e-bf4a-2f03c3aaa7e0\", \"0d080dce-5d88-4a9e-bf4a-2f03c3aaa7e0\"]", 
                        "[\"0d3e9a6a-fa96-40b4-b0ec-23f792c9abcf\", \"0d3e9a6a-fa96-40b4-b0ec-23f792c9abcf\"]", 
                        "[\"10fcff07-12aa-4034-b03f-15e6e73cf310\", \"10fcff07-12aa-4034-b03f-15e6e73cf310\"]", 
                        "[\"137997b0-edde-4898-80dd-090f49905d17\", \"137997b0-edde-4898-80dd-090f49905d17\"]", 
                        "[\"1d663037-28b0-4f37-b1ed-ffdaa237b1b9\", \"1d663037-28b0-4f37-b1ed-ffdaa237b1b9\"]", 
                        "[\"25f51039-f3ef-46d8-94b8-a90aa9c8a6d2\", \"25f51039-f3ef-46d8-94b8-a90aa9c8a6d2\"]", 
                        "[\"298837cc-889b-4fd8-931f-6b47665158e6\", \"298837cc-889b-4fd8-931f-6b47665158e6\"]", 
                        "[\"2ba1fb3c-7d8a-4a28-ba94-631324fc164c\", \"2ba1fb3c-7d8a-4a28-ba94-631324fc164c\"]", 
                        "[\"2d96c883-e24d-4566-bc25-19e5a11417d2\", \"2d96c883-e24d-4566-bc25-19e5a11417d2\"]", 
                        "[\"349d6cd3-ac21-4a4f-a0af-7706bb7c3022\", \"349d6cd3-ac21-4a4f-a0af-7706bb7c3022\"]", 
                        "[\"34fec690-ee08-4eaf-b270-a872972bafe4\", \"34fec690-ee08-4eaf-b270-a872972bafe4\"]", 
                        "[\"35814c64-2619-4513-9b0e-f30814b11117\", \"35814c64-2619-4513-9b0e-f30814b11117\"]", 
                        "[\"40cd26f4-6fd2-477e-91fa-d2542315b30e\", \"40cd26f4-6fd2-477e-91fa-d2542315b30e\"]", 
                        "[\"41a162db-7ba7-4ad9-ace9-1d9bb0536ead\", \"41a162db-7ba7-4ad9-ace9-1d9bb0536ead\"]", 
                        "[\"44e2deb1-ad2c-46d0-bed2-5b23b71ddbeb\", \"44e2deb1-ad2c-46d0-bed2-5b23b71ddbeb\"]", 
                        "[\"524481fc-d949-4371-b179-63e76d949979\", \"524481fc-d949-4371-b179-63e76d949979\"]", 
                        "[\"5ad11ecd-93cf-4166-96c9-6e152ac58667\", \"5ad11ecd-93cf-4166-96c9-6e152ac58667\"]", 
                        "[\"5aea2cbe-33da-48fa-a90d-31da2b108c2d\", \"5aea2cbe-33da-48fa-a90d-31da2b108c2d\"]", 
                        "[\"5d265d15-a16c-4683-9276-66c592e09ba5\", \"5d265d15-a16c-4683-9276-66c592e09ba5\"]", 
                        "[\"6795fd6d-364f-4e63-b656-98b2cf0eed91\", \"6795fd6d-364f-4e63-b656-98b2cf0eed91\"]", 
                        "[\"6a1352a7-5986-4fda-8bc6-98630ffbd967\", \"6a1352a7-5986-4fda-8bc6-98630ffbd967\"]", 
                        "[\"6d5abb48-5413-4347-8d1d-af722098d803\", \"6d5abb48-5413-4347-8d1d-af722098d803\"]", 
                        "[\"702a1754-bc75-4cc8-81bd-d03598b21292\", \"702a1754-bc75-4cc8-81bd-d03598b21292\"]", 
                        "[\"71dd628d-e3eb-46e8-ace4-b102cde0e94f\", \"71dd628d-e3eb-46e8-ace4-b102cde0e94f\"]", 
                        "[\"76b67664-5fee-45b0-ae4f-4b7f53d69779\", \"76b67664-5fee-45b0-ae4f-4b7f53d69779\"]", 
                        "[\"79227dcb-9930-4734-8b8e-efbd4f7ba396\", \"79227dcb-9930-4734-8b8e-efbd4f7ba396\"]", 
                        "[\"7d323987-b873-441d-8e5e-9e9124628468\", \"7d323987-b873-441d-8e5e-9e9124628468\"]", 
                        "[\"807ebe50-8369-4a8d-8176-4b449cdb2932\", \"807ebe50-8369-4a8d-8176-4b449cdb2932\"]", 
                        "[\"8092cc86-1b99-4547-9221-86f97c85bbe7\", \"8092cc86-1b99-4547-9221-86f97c85bbe7\"]", 
                        "[\"819dab0e-ba20-4f4e-80c3-c16f4f9a69a7\", \"819dab0e-ba20-4f4e-80c3-c16f4f9a69a7\"]", 
                        "[\"84329c2c-3d81-48a8-a879-d376b0141b58\", \"84329c2c-3d81-48a8-a879-d376b0141b58\"]", 
                        "[\"88e95e56-861f-4ed3-a745-73f678769a6e\", \"88e95e56-861f-4ed3-a745-73f678769a6e\"]", 
                        "[\"9281aea6-8e7a-4f42-8715-2f185c07894d\", \"9281aea6-8e7a-4f42-8715-2f185c07894d\"]", 
                        "[\"96d1c8c9-d2e4-47d4-a0da-391fe94a1213\", \"96d1c8c9-d2e4-47d4-a0da-391fe94a1213\"]", 
                        "[\"9ed56f80-e34a-4447-b550-6e0f03f809a5\", \"9ed56f80-e34a-4447-b550-6e0f03f809a5\"]", 
                        "[\"a41c232f-6014-417f-b321-e66fc2f306a5\", \"a41c232f-6014-417f-b321-e66fc2f306a5\"]", 
                        "[\"aab965ce-e656-49c7-b66d-2f13cf26df3f\", \"aab965ce-e656-49c7-b66d-2f13cf26df3f\"]", 
                        "[\"af4eb4ec-f8c0-40cb-bc70-09db103c1eb7\", \"af4eb4ec-f8c0-40cb-bc70-09db103c1eb7\"]", 
                        "[\"b8825d8b-a662-4c4c-9b38-7f855e795500\", \"b8825d8b-a662-4c4c-9b38-7f855e795500\"]", 
                        "[\"bc88917c-1145-4e47-b06b-a15f111a7792\", \"bc88917c-1145-4e47-b06b-a15f111a7792\"]", 
                        "[\"bf264dc4-85c8-49db-b43e-cf9d6cc759b0\", \"bf264dc4-85c8-49db-b43e-cf9d6cc759b0\"]", 
                        "[\"cc4bc22b-ce9c-4c56-8760-d36ccd5ac446\", \"cc4bc22b-ce9c-4c56-8760-d36ccd5ac446\"]", 
                        "[\"ce48aaeb-6f6d-4bd7-b9eb-dc45b9a58032\", \"ce48aaeb-6f6d-4bd7-b9eb-dc45b9a58032\"]", 
                        "[\"d0456d39-b3e0-4b86-af46-12d4cbcc7dcd\", \"d0456d39-b3e0-4b86-af46-12d4cbcc7dcd\"]", 
                        "[\"d41b7f5e-3ebb-40c6-9a3e-80e925ded2bb\", \"d41b7f5e-3ebb-40c6-9a3e-80e925ded2bb\"]", 
                        "[\"d842e6c3-0161-47fa-a725-2fd23bfb3cc8\", \"d842e6c3-0161-47fa-a725-2fd23bfb3cc8\"]", 
                        "[\"da991efa-4c25-489f-b813-caed1fb9a202\", \"da991efa-4c25-489f-b813-caed1fb9a202\"]", 
                        "[\"db2a6c16-66ba-4de4-8d9b-47817cf1259b\", \"db2a6c16-66ba-4de4-8d9b-47817cf1259b\"]", 
                        "[\"e0e81bb6-2972-4ae5-ae1c-cbcc886221ae\", \"e0e81bb6-2972-4ae5-ae1c-cbcc886221ae\"]", 
                        "[\"e80403d1-15e7-4bbf-86db-85148b67baa8\", \"e80403d1-15e7-4bbf-86db-85148b67baa8\"]", 
                        "[\"f2667a05-b80b-491e-8f56-b0a17f62ff09\", \"f2667a05-b80b-491e-8f56-b0a17f62ff09\"]", 
                        "[\"f2e00229-cc20-4201-9548-912ed7d53299\", \"f2e00229-cc20-4201-9548-912ed7d53299\"]", 
                        "[\"f4fbd56d-84e5-4fa8-9610-286e779160ff\", \"f4fbd56d-84e5-4fa8-9610-286e779160ff\"]", 
                        "[\"fae208a5-97de-465c-8b12-fb7532edadec\", \"fae208a5-97de-465c-8b12-fb7532edadec\"]"
                    ],
                    "IsEmpty" : [ 
                        "[false, false]"
                    ],
                    "Tags.KeyValue" : [ 
                        "[\"01fbe4f9-77a5-48a2-8a3d-6b105808f6ackey6_ddd_01fbe4f9-77a5-48a2-8a3d-6b105808f6acvalue6\", \"01fbe4f9-77a5-48a2-8a3d-6b105808f6ackey6_ddd_01fbe4f9-77a5-48a2-8a3d-6b105808f6acvalue6\"]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 171412,
                "seeks" : 172,
                "dupsTested" : 171240,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many documents do you have? If you want to compare performance between indexes, you need to have at least 10M - 20M records

Comment: I test on 11M documents

Comment: Share please `.explain("executionStats")` for both queries

Comment: added execution stats